# UISearchBar not working even with delegate set in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8.1, xcode6.4

The `searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked` method isn't firing when I tap on the search bar. I have already added the `self.searchBar.deleagate = self;` and in my .h file I added the `<UISearchBarDelegate>`.

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMap;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   self.searchBar.delegate = self;
   self.myMap.delegate = self;
}

- (void)searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked:(UISearchBar * )searchBar{
NSLog(@"working");

[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
NSLog(@"working");

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[geocoder geocodeAddressString:self.searchBar.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newLocation = [placemark.location coordinate];
    region.center = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region center];

    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [annotation setCoordinate:newLocation];
    [annotation setTitle:self.searchBar.text];
    [self.myMap addAnnotation:annotation];

    MKMapRect mr = [self.myMap visibleMapRect];
    MKMapPoint pt = MKMapPointForCoordinate([annotation coordinate]);
    mr.origin.x = pt.x - mr.size.width * 0.5;
    mr.origin.y = pt.y -mr.size.width * 0.25;
    [self.myMap setVisibleMapRect:mr animated:YES];
}];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Rahul! Turns out I was using the wrong method!

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate>

  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMap;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  self.searchBar.delegate = self;
  self.myMap.delegate = self;
}

- (void)searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked:(UISearchBar * )searchBar{

[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[geocoder geocodeAddressString:self.searchBar.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
MKCoordinateRegion region;
CLLocationCoordinate2D newLocation = [placemark.location coordinate];
region.center = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region center];

MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[annotation setCoordinate:newLocation];
[annotation setTitle:self.searchBar.text];
[self.myMap addAnnotation:annotation];

MKMapRect mr = [self.myMap visibleMapRect];
MKMapPoint pt = MKMapPointForCoordinate([annotation coordinate]);
mr.origin.x = pt.x - mr.size.width * 0.5;
mr.origin.y = pt.y -mr.size.width * 0.25;
[self.myMap setVisibleMapRect:mr animated:YES];
}];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have

1. All delegate being set properly, this can be done either in code or
   in storyboard.
2. Make use of correct delegate method to capture the
       event.

If you think

```
- (void)searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked:(UISearchBar * )searchBar
```

then try using the other method which is more straight forward to trigger search

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this UISearchBar delegate method:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked for being able to fire it, but I do not know if that is the proper method to use. Only because now when I run my entire code none of my annotations are working and my pin is thrown somewhere in the Africa